# Send dataset of MSSQL 2012 (Stored in Local PC) of C# windows Desktop Software to Android App Via PHP Website

Tags: c#, php, android, sql-server, synchronization

How to Send dataset of MSSQL 2012(Stored in Local PC) of C# windows Desktop Software to PHP website Hosted Online(e.g. www.mysite.com)? Then fetch those data from Android Application.

So I want `C#(Windows Software) --> PHP Website --> Android`

**Note.:-** Local PC has only Internet Connection. No Static IP(Live IP). Cant Build Webservice for desktop PC.

Comment: I think the best alternative here is to build an API and access it. That way you do not need to go through the PHP web site and then to Android. Both the PHP website and the Android application can access the API from the same end point. But, that is not possible without a static IP. A static IP is required.

Comment: I know the API with static ip..but as per client's system its not possible..